# Taking two cells as arguments, and return a specific value depending on the string value of the cells

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a VBA function that uses the values of two cells as arguments, and then return something depending on the values of the cells. I was thinking something like this

```
   Function returnNewString (cell1,cell2):
    if cell1 == 'somestring' && cell2 == "someotherstring" then
    return "something"
    else if cell1 == 'somestring2' && cell2 == "someotherstring2" then
    return "something else"
   end function
```

A function call of `returnNewString(A1,B1)` should therefore return 'something' in relation to the conditions.

Comment: Are you sure you are working in VBA? Your code example looks nothing like VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested If/Case statements. Pretty simple, just check the value of the first string then proceed to check the value of the 2nd.

In your particular situation, I would go for Select Case Statements, but it comes down to preference in the end.

```
Function returnNewString(sValue1 As String, sValue2 As String) As String

    Select Case sValue1
    Case "Some String"
        Select Case sValue2
        Case "SomeOtherString"
            returnNewString = "Something"
        Case "Some Other String 2"
            returnNewString = "Something else"
        End Select
    Case "Some String 2"
        Select Case sValue2
        Case "SomeOtherString"
            returnNewString = "Something"
        Case "Some Other String 2"
            returnNewString = "Something else"
        End Select
    End Select

End Function
```

In the first Select case, you check the value of the first argument `sValue1`. Once you match that value, proceed to check the value of `sValue2`.

And the syntax you used in your example is incorrect - there are no `==` and `&&` operators in VBA, and literal string values must be enclosed in double-quotes, not single quotes - single quotes are reserved for comments.

Comment: This will give a different result to the OPs code (eg if cell1 is "Some String" and cell2 is "Some Other String 2")

Comment: Yes and no - I was trying to demonstrate his options. However, he can simply remove the 2nd statement in the 2nd select case and the first statement in the other if he truly wanted them to match 1 on 1. But someone who is obviously not familiar with VBA should have had that explained to them in the answer at the very least, which I failed to properly do.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completness, the implementation of your pseudo code as written would be (which would be case senstitive)

```
Function returnNewString (cell1 As Variant, cell2 As Variant) As Variant
    If cell1 = "somestring" And cell2 = "someotherstring" Then
        returnNewString = "something"
    ElseIf cell1 = "somestring2" And cell2 = "someotherstring2" Then
        returnNewString = "something else"
    End If
End Function
```